# With regular expression, transform separated words into a reference

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

With PHP, I'm trying to use preg_replace to convert a group of words separated with an underline into a "reference" composed of the first letter of each word except for the last one in the group I want to retrieve it first 4 letters (or less if the last word is less than 3 letters).

Better than words, an example.

**1. this_is_one_example -> tioexam** ("this_" -> t ; "is_" -> i ; "one_" -> o ; "example" -> exam)

**2. another_example -> aexam** ("another_" -> a ; "example" -> exam)

**3. yet_another_example -> yaexam** ("yet_' -> y ; "another_" -> a ; "example" -> exam

I tryied

```
$reference = preg_replace('/(([A-Za-z])[A-Za-z]+_)/', '$2', $words);
```

I got :

1. tioexam
2. aexample
3. yaexample

That's a good start, but I can't find what to write in the regular expression for the last part.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the `\G` anchor to get consecutive matches from the start of the string and a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) to use a single group in the replacement.

Using the case insensitive flag:

```
\G(?|([a-z])[a-z]+_|(?<=_)([a-z]{1,4})[a-z]*$)
```

**Explanation**

- `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match or at the start, in this case at the start
- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `([a-z])[a-z]+_` Capture **group 1**, match a single char a-zA-Z followed by 1+ chars a-z and an underscore (use `[a-z]*` to match 0+ chars)
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<=_)` Positive lookbehind, assert an underscore to the left
  - `([a-z]{1,4})[a-z]*$` Capture **group 2**, match 1-4 chars a-zA-Z and 0+ chars a-zA-Z followed by the end of the line
- `)` Close branch reset group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XIHWf6/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/H9X6U)

For example

```
$words = [
    "this_is_one_example",
    "another_example",
    "yet_another_example",
    "this is a test_test",
    "test",
    "_test"
];

$pattern = '/\G(?|([a-z])[a-z]+_|(?<=_)([a-z]{1,4})[a-z]*$)/i';

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $reference = preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $word);
    echo $reference . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
tioexam
aexam
yaexam
this is a test_test
test
_test
```

Comment: I really like your solution with `\G` (+1) - however test it with [`test_123_123`](https://regex101.com/r/XIHWf6/3) - not sure if OP allows digits though.

Comment: @Jan Thanks :-) I see `[A-Za-z]` in the question, my assumption is those chars only. It can be extended to `[A-Za-z0-9]` in that case.

Comment: Nice introduction to `\G`, I have never seen this used but can see it being very useful in future. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 1):

**<s>Original Answer</s>**

```
$reference = preg_replace('/(([a-z])[^_]*_)|(([a-z]{1,4})[a-z]*$)/i', '$2$4', $words);
```

---

**Updated Answer**

```
$reference = preg_replace('/\G(?|([a-z])[a-z]*_|([a-z]{1,4})[a-z]*$)/i', '$1', $words);
```

---

Credit to *@The fourth bird* for introducing me to the extremely useful branch reset group, which I have never seen used until today and will certainly add to my regex arsenal. This allows us to more effectively match one of two different patterns but deliver them as one capture group, something I was otherwise having to use two capture groups for.

I believe my actual regex is slightly more optimised and gives the correct output in cases such as `a_example` which *@The fourth bird*'s will not. I also think a lookbehind for an underscore on the final group is unnecessary and will actually cause a string with only one part to be ignored (e.g. `example`).

With this regex we get the following results:

`this_is_one_example` becomes `tioexam`

`another_example` becomes `aexam`

`a_example` becomes `aexam`

`example` becomes `exam`

Answer (score 1):

Just saying - no regular expressions needed, really:

```
<?php

function abbr($string) {
    $splitted = explode("_", $string);

    if (count($splitted) > 1) {
        $numItems = count($splitted);
        $i = 0;
        $result = [];
        foreach ($splitted as $key => $value) {
            if (++$i === $numItems) {
                $result[] = substr($value, 0, 4);

            } else {
                $result[] = $value[0];
            }
        }
        return implode("", $result);
    } else {
        return $string;
    }
}

$strings = ["this_is_one_example", "another_example", "yet_another_example", "lorem ipsum", "test_123", "nothinghere", 123];

$result = array_map("abbr", $strings);
print_r($result);
?>
```

This returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => tioexam
    [1] => aexam
    [2] => yaexam
    [3] => lorem ipsum
    [4] => t123
    [5] => nothinghere
    [6] => 123
)
```

Or - if you want to filter out what has passed / failed, return an array instead:

```
function abbr($string) {
    $splitted = explode("_", $string);

    if (count($splitted) > 1) {
        $numItems = count($splitted);
        $i = 0;
        $result = [];
        foreach ($splitted as $key => $value) {
            if (++$i === $numItems) {
                $result[] = substr($value, 0, 4);

            } else {
                $result[] = $value[0];
            }
        }
        return [true, implode("", $result)];
    } else {
        return [false, $string];
    }
}
```

Which would yield

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => tioexam
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => aexam
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => yaexam
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => lorem ipsum
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => t123
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => nothinghere
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 123
        )

)
```